# reading file from css link in python

Tags: python, web-crawler

I have a link to a squarespace hosted css file: http://static.squarespace.com/universal/styles-compressed/audio-player-6c42d60d26f4e09ab1ac335b4bc55b7e-min.css

I would like to read the file using `python 2.7` and then save it to my disk. what I have so far is more or less

```
import os
import urllib2
import requests

css = "http://static.squarespace.com/universal/styles-compressed/audio-player-6c42d60d26f4e09ab1ac335b4bc55b7e-min.css"


contents = urllib2.urlopen(css)
```

which throws error: `unknown url type: static.squarespace.com/universal/styles-compressed/audio-player-6c42d60d26f4e09ab1ac335b4bc55b7e-min.css`

presumably because the `.css` link is not a `URL`?

what is the proper way to read the content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question:

```
import urllib

link = "http://static.squarespace.com/universal/styles-compressed/audio-player-6c42d60d26f4e09ab1ac335b4bc55b7e-min.css"
f = urllib.urlopen(link)
myfile = f.read()
print(myfile)
```

You need to use`read()` for reading file.

Or, it is better to use `requests` for this action.

```
import requests

link = "http://static.squarespace.com/universal/styles-compressed/audio-player-6c42d60d26f4e09ab1ac335b4bc55b7e-min.css"
f = requests.get(link)

print(f.text) # or f.content (for byte type)
```

You may need this [Requests doc](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/).